# Dynamically adding HTML fields with Javascript and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I've been having a lot of troubles with this for the past few hours right now and I'm really not seeing where the problem is. Every single code snippet I find on the Internet is telling me I'm doing it right, but for some reason, nothing is working.

Basically, I have a form that requires fields to be dynamically added depending on the number of fields needed. My javascript to do this works fine:

```
    function ajouterStagiaires()
    {
    var innerHTML = new String();
    innerHTML = document.getElementById('stagiaires').innerHTML;
    var nombreStagiaires = document.getElementById('nbStagiairesConnus').value;

    innerHTML += "<tr><td><b>Nom </b></td><td><b>Matricule</b> </td></tr>";
    for(var i=0;i<nombreStagiaires;i++)
    {
        innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='noms[]' /></td><td><input type='text' name='matricules[]' /></td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById('stagiaires').innerHTML = innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('nbStagiairesConnus').value = nombreStagiaires;

}
```

The fields are added properly in the page, but when I go to my PHP code, the $_POSTs done on noms and matricules are not being "detected" (yes, I have things entered in my fields in the web page).

```
if (isset($_POST['matricules']))
{
  echo "foo";
}
```

The "foo" is never printed. I have troubleshooted most of the common mistakes: my fields being added ARE in the form (CodeIgniter's echo form_open_multipart('foobar');). Every other field inside the form works perfectly fine.

The only thing I can see is that CodeIgniter is having problems with the JavaScript or something of the kind (though I don't know WHY it would have problems with it...) but other than that, I am completely stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, where you are adding your input fields, put in a value = '' as well.

> innerHTML += ... "input type='text' name='noms[]' value='' ..

In your CI controller, try this instead:

> $matricules[] = $this->input->post("matricules");
>
> if(is_array($matricules))
>      print_r($matricules);

This should pretty print the array of values passed from the form.

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check the sourcecode and verify whether the fields are actually added where you want them.